# iOS Segmented Controls

Tags: ios, controls, apple, segmented

I'm trying to figure out the use cases for the different sizes of segmented controls, specifically the 2 segmented one.
The app store has a longer version (located below the Nav bar), while the iTunes store has a smaller, more compact one (located in the Nav bar).

Anyone know why Apple has done this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Different design teams.

The app store bar is not in the nav bar has a longer title, so I assume it did not fit.

The iTunes one, probably a stronger focus on the content to have those pixels available for selling.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, but I'm not sure those are valid answers though.